# Row Count in Result using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am having following query

```
;with a as (
  select Id,Type,Description from wo)
  select * from a
```

Output

```
 Id    Type    Description 
 1      a        sadf
 2      a        ewrw
 3      b        223
```

I need one more cloumn with total count of all rows like below

```
 Id    Type    Description   RowCount
 1      a        sadf          3 
 2      a        ewrw          3
 3      b        223           3
```

How to solve this with using CTE 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(*) over ()` in 2005+

```
;with a as (
  select Id,
         Type,
         Description, 
         count(*) over () as "RowCount"
  from wo)
  select * 
  from a
```

Though it isn't apparent why you need the CTE at all.

```
  select Id,
         Type,
         Description, 
         count(*) over () as "RowCount"
  from wo
```

Would also work.